# Find all possible pairs

Tags: list, recursion, erlang, tuples

Im working on some erlang code and want to create a recursive function for extracting all possible pairs from a list. The list could have zero elements, but it could have up to 70 elements. Writing cases for all of these occurrences is bad practice and I would like your help.

```
pair(List) ->
    case List of
        []              -> [];
        [A]             -> [{A}];
        [A, B]          -> [{A, B}, {B, A}];
        [A, B, C]       -> [{A, B}, {A, C}, {B, A}, {B, C}, {C, A}, {C, B}];
    end.
```

I found a function written to create a list of all possible combinations (not only all pairs), but I don't understand how to change it.

```
combos(1, L) -> [[X] || X <-L];
combos(K, L) when K == length(L) -> [L];
combos(K, [H|T]) ->
    [[H | Subcombos] || Subcombos <- combos(K-1, T)]
    ++(combos(K, T)).

combos(L) ->
    lists:foldl(
        fun(K, Acc) -> Acc++(combos(K, L)) end,
        [[]], lists:seq(1, length(L))).
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension and reference the same list twice as an input:

```
1> L = [a,b,c,d].
[a,b,c,d]
2> [{X, Y} || X <- L, Y <- L].
[{a,a},
 {a,b},
 {a,c},
 {a,d},
 {b,a},
 {b,b},
 {b,c},
 {b,d},
 {c,a},
 {c,b},
 {c,c},
 {c,d},
 {d,a},
 {d,b},
 {d,c},
 {d,d}]
```

I'd be surprised if there was any clearer *or* more efficient way to do this.

**EDIT**

In the event you don't want identical pairs (`{a,a}` and so on) you can add a guard to ensure inequality:

```
5> [{X, Y} || X <- L1, Y <- L1, X /= Y]. 
[{a,b},
 {a,c},
 {a,d},
 {b,a},
 {b,c},
 {b,d},
 {c,a},
 {c,b},
 {c,d},
 {d,a},
 {d,b},
 {d,c}]
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I want except for the pairs with the same variables (i.e {a, a}, {b, b} and so on). Is there a way using guards in the list comprehension?

Comment: @Oscar Certainly, a guard at the end to guarantee inequality will do the trick.